# Implementing eigen decomposition

Tags: pca, matrix

## Question

Please help understand why the eigen vectors do not match below. If there are misunderstandings or incorrect place, please correct too. It would be much appreciated.

## Eigen decomposition

According to eigen decomposition, a matrix **A** can be decomposed as $A = PDP^{-1}$. Trying to implement it and verify by using [numpy.linalg.eig](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html).

[image]

First generate **A** from **P** and **D**.

### Eigen vector matrix P

Define **P** as a row ordered matrix where the row $\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_1}} = \left [ cos(\theta), sin(\theta) \right ]$ and $\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_2}} = \left [ -sin(\theta), cos(\theta) \right ]$ are eigen vectors.

$\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) \\ -sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$

```
import numpy as np

THETA = np.pi / 12

def get_eigen_vector_matrix(theta):
    return np.array([
        [np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)],
        [-np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]
    ])

P = get_eigen_vector_matrix(THETA)
print(P)
-----
[[ 0.96592583  0.25881905]
 [-0.25881905  0.96592583]]
```

### Eigen value diagonal matrix D

D extends the eigen vector $\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_1}}$ for $\lambda_1$ times and  $\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_2}}$ for $\lambda_2$ times.

$D = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}$

```
D = np.array([
    [3, 0],
    [0, 2]
])
print(D)
-----
[[3 0]
 [0 2]]
```

## Projection Matrix $A = PDP^{-1}$

Generate **A** from **P** and **D**.

Projection by the matrix $A \cdot \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = P \cdot D \cdot P^{-1} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ where:

1. $P^{-1} \cdot x$ maps the coefficients of $x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} $ in space **X** in purple into those of $u = \begin{bmatrix}u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix} $ in space **U** in orange
   where the eigen vectors $(\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_1}}, \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_2}})$ are the basis vectors in **U**.
2. $D \cdot u$ extends the coefficent of $\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_1}}$ by $\lambda_1$ times and that of $\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_2}}$ by $\lambda_2$ times as $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1u_1 \\ \lambda_2u_2 \end{bmatrix}$.
3. $P$ projects $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1u_1 \\ \lambda_2u_2 \end{bmatrix}$ back to space **X**.

```
A = P @ D @ np.linalg.inv(P)
print(A)
-----
[[ 2.9330127 -0.25     ]
 [-0.25       2.0669873]]
```

### Verify the eigen vector matrix P

Verify the eigen vectors of **A** using [numpy.linalg.eig](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html). It returns eigen vectors as matrix **v** where columns are the eigen vectors.

> [image]

```
l, e = np.linalg.eig(A)
print(l)      # eigen values lambda
print(e.T)    # eigen vectors e. Transposing it to be a row oriented matrix.
-----
[3. 2.]
[[ 0.96592583 -0.25881905]
 [ 0.25881905  0.96592583]]
```

## Problem

However, the result from `np.linalg.eig(A)` does not match **P**.

```
print(e.T)    # eigen vectors e. Transposing it to be a row oriented matrix.
-----
[[ 0.96592583 -0.25881905]
 [ 0.25881905  0.96592583]]
```

```
print(P)
-----
[[ 0.96592583  0.25881905]
 [-0.25881905  0.96592583]]
```

## Investigation

It seems that if I want the expression $A = PDP^{-1}$ to be valid, then **P** should have been defined as a column ordered matrix as $\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) \\ sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$ where  column $\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_1}} = \begin{bmatrix} cos(\theta) \\ sin(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$ and $\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_2}} = \begin{bmatrix} -sin(\theta) \\ cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$ are eigen vectors.

If I use the row ordered matrix as in the original **P**, then the decomposition should have been stated as $A = P^TD(P^T)^{-1}$.

```
_A = P.T @ D @ np.linalg.inv(P.T)
print(_A)
-----
[[2.9330127 0.25     ]
 [0.25      2.0669873]]

_l, _e = np.linalg.eig(_A)
print(_l)      # eigen values lambda
print(_e.T)    # eigen vectors e. Transpose to be row oriented
-----
[3. 2.]
[[ 0.96592583  0.25881905]        # matches with P
 [-0.25881905  0.96592583]]
```

Please help confirm if this is true.

If true, then I think I should be specific and careful with how I layout the vectors into a matrix format, $P = \begin{bmatrix} \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_1}} \\ \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_2}} \end{bmatrix}$ or  $P = \begin{bmatrix} \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_1}} & \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_2}} \end{bmatrix}$.

In text book or articles, apparently $P = \begin{bmatrix} \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_1}} & \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{p_2}} \end{bmatrix}$ is being used by default and the matrix is, to me, in the column order format.

Which confuses me why it has become this way, and why row or column order is not discussed nor clarified. Because if I use row-order format to layout the eigen vectors, I get a wrong result.

If someone can help me to demystify, I really appreciate.

## Related

- [Matrix - rules on using row oriented or column oriented [closed]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595352)